# is there an equivalent to Stata's egen function?

Tags: r, stata

Stata has a very nice command, `egen`, which makes it easy to compute statistics over group of observation. For instance, it is possible to compute the max, the mean and the min for each group and add them as a variable in the detailed data set. The Stata command is one line of code :

```
by group : egen max = max(x)
```

I've never found the same command in R. `summarise` in the `dplyr` package makes it easy to compute statistics for each group but then I have to run a loop to associate the statistic to each observation :

```
library("dplyr")
N  <- 1000
tf  <- data.frame(group = sample(1:100, size = N, replace = TRUE), x = rnorm(N))
table(tf$group)
mtf  <- summarise(group_by(tbl_df(tf), group), max = max(x))
tf$max  <- NA
for (i in 1:nrow(mtf)) {
  tf$max[tf$group == mtf$group[i]]  <- mtf$max[i]
}
```

Does any one has a better solution ?

Comment: There is a number of alternatives. Your question shows a lack of research (you didn't even study the dplyr package vignette). -1

Comment: I have no bias against `egen` (I wrote some of the functions) but  even from a Stata viewpoint it is just a handy collection of stuff for creating variables. There's no central idea that maps onto anything that would be a central idea in R. Even the convenience of producing summary statistics by group is not in fact part of the definition or role of `egen` but just something possible with some of its components. I won't speak for R but I suspect some of its packages are also a bit miscellaneous.

Comment: I agree with you but it still really useful.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here are a few approaches:

**dplyr**

```
library(dplyr)

tf %>% group_by(group) %>% mutate(max = max(x))
```

**ave**

This uses only the base of R:

```
transform(tf, max = ave(x, group, FUN = max))
```

**data.table**

```
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(tf)
dt[, max:=max(x), by=group]
```